# An electronic tool for mixing while the pot is on the fire

Tags: equipment

When cooking a pudding cream, we need to constantly mix the cream while it is on the fire, in order to prevent chunks from forming and keep the cream smooth. It takes a long time and the hand becomes tired. Is there an electronic tool that can be used to mix the cream while it is on the fire?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, when you say on the fire, do you just mean when its cooking, or are you referring to a specific method I'm just not familiar with?

Comment: I mean: when it is cooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For thick sauces and puddings, I would think an immersion blender is the way to go. [Some](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CDTMWG) even have removable shafts, so you can change the length of stick attachment to fit your pot, or switch it out for different accessories, like a [whisk attachment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AZKGGW). And at risk of sounding like an infomercial, they even sell [bowl clamps](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00197CFVU) for hands free operation!

Me personally, I like a drill and [mixer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Wal-Board-Tools-1-4-in-x-11-in-Steel-Power-Mixer-81-004/100392767) attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a Thermomix would do the job?  ...or a magnetic stirrer/hotplate?  Search Chemistry supply houses.  Though the pudding may be too thick for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

There exist automatic pot stirrers:

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0000TPBYG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000TPBYG)
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B013L1XYU2/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013L1XYU2)
- [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004JELGHE/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004JELGHE)
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00F3WUB8Q/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F3WUB8Q)

... but unless it's just the right size for the pot, I would think that you would run into issues with it not clearing the corners of the pot well, and scorching the cream.

(note : I've never used any of them ... and the product pages don't show the working end of the device except for the last one ... which obviously won't get to the corners)

Comment: I can't speak for the other 3, but I've actually seen the 4th stirrer (robostir) in action.  It will move around the bottom of the pot, so it will actually get into the corners.  The one thing you'll have to watch out for is that it doesn't have too much power--it was designed for soups and sauces, nothing too thick.